# Binding a function to a parent div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pretty new to programming, I am working on a project for a friend but my functions stop working after a section of my code is loaded dynamically. I have a button that clones a section of my form and auto increments the input ID's. I tried rewriting the functions and adding a 2 after the input name but the functions still cease to work.  I spoke to a developer friend who said that if I bind my function to parent div tag it should fix it but I don't know how to do that. Hope I explained myself enough.

**Here is an example of one of my JS functions which should show/hide a div tag and its contents**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFieldsnow();

    $("#typeofinstallation").change(function () {
        toggleFieldsnow();
    });

});

function toggleFieldsnow() {
    if ($("#typeofinstallation").val() == "Snow_Melt")
        $("#show_hide_sm").show();
    else
        $("#show_hide_sm").hide();
}
```

**Here is a snippet of my HTML Code**

```
<div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle_other.js"></script>
  <h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">
<span id="Zone"></span></h2>

   <!--<p name="reference"><strong>Note:</strong> Please use <strong>zone 1</strong> as a template for any additional zones you would like to create, then click add zone. Then  fill out the required information. Menu options and fields may change depending on what you select for your zone.</p>-->

  <fieldset>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group"><!-- end .select_ttl -->
  </div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="label_fn control-label" for="ZoneName"><a href="http://www.pexheat.com/site/helpFilesFolder/zoneName.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://www.pexheat.com/site/helpFilesFolder/zoneName.html','1395159238843','width=500,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;"><u>Zone Name</u></a>:</label>
  <input name="ZoneName" type="text" required class="input_fn form-control" id="ZoneName" placeholder="" value="Zone 1" title="Please enter a name for the zone. This name will be use to distinguish this zone from others in your project." style="background:#FFFFCC;">
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group" id="show_hide_dr">
  <label class="label_ln control-label" for="DesignTemp"><a href="http://www.pexheat.com/site/helpFilesFolder/designRoomTemperature.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://www.pexheat.com/site/helpFilesFolder/designRoomTemperature.html','1395159238843','width=500,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;"><u>Design Room Temp</u></a>:</label>
  <input name="DesignTemp" type="text" class="input_ln form-control" id="DesignTemp" placeholder="68" value="" title="" style="background:#FFFFCC;">
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="show_hide_sm">
  <label class="label_sm control-label" for="SnowMelting"><u>Snow Melting Class</u></a>:</label>
  <input name="SnowMelting" type="text" class="input_sm form-control" id="SnowMelting" placeholder="(1 to 3; 1 = Residential, 3 = Commercial)"title="Required Field" style="background:#FFFFCC;">
</div>
</div>
```

I tried the below code but now the function does not work at all when the webpage loads

As per your suggestion I  tried the code below but now the function does not work at all. I know I am probably doing something wrong.

```
$('entry1').on('change', '#typeofinstallation', function () {
    toggleFieldsnow();
});

function toggleFieldsnow() {
    if ($("#typeofinstallation").val() == "Snow_Melt")
        $("#show_hide_sm").show();
    else
        $("#show_hide_sm").hide();
}
```

This is the code that I am trying to bind the function to :

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="label_toi control-label" for="typeofinstallation"><a href="http://www.pexheat.com/site/helpFilesFolder/typeOfInstallation.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://www.pexheat.com/site/helpFilesFolder/typeOfInstallation.html','1395159238843','width=500,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;"><u>Type of Installation</u></a>:</label>
          <select name="typeofinstallation" class="input_toi form-control" id="typeofinstallation" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" title="The type of radiant floor installation is usually determined by the construction of the zone. All types of radiant floor installation (except electric) typically have more than enough heating capacity for a zone. The differences in efficiency and response of the types are mostly insignificant. Your main concerns in choosing an installation type should be cost and effort of installation. See the help text for each installation type for details.">
            <option selected="" value="1">(Choose One)</option>
  <option value="Concrete">Concrete Slab</option>
  <option value="Staple">Staple-Up </option>
  <option value="Above">Above Floor Sleeper System </option>
  <option value="Baseboard">Baseboard  </option>
  <option value="Fan">Fan Coil </option>
  <option value="Snow_Melt">Snow Melting </option>
</select>
        </div>

<div class="form-group" id="show_hide_sm">
  <label class="label_sm control-label" for="SnowMelting"><u>Snow Melting Class</u></a>:</label>
  <input name="SnowMelting" type="text" class="input_sm form-control" id="SnowMelting" placeholder="(1 to 3; 1 = Residential, 3 = Commercial)"title="Required Field" style="background:#FFFFCC;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dynamic content is being appended to the HTML snippet shown, use the parent element there (which appears to be `#entry1`) instead of `body` in my example:

```
$('body').on('change', '#typeofinstallation', function () {
    toggleFieldsnow();
});
```

Comment: I tried that but maybe I am still doing something wrong

Comment: Can you post an example of the select element you are trying to bind to?

Comment: Did you try using the 'body' selector as I posted it? I'm guessing the content is not getting appended to `#entry1`